# a4j:commandButton doesn't work inside rich:modalPanel

Tags: jsf, richfaces

I'm using rich:ModalPanel to insert some users but the action in my commandButton doesn't seem to respond.

```
<rich:modalPanel id="panel" moveable="true" top="150" width="400" autosized="true">   

<h:form id="uploadForm">  

     <a4j:outputPanel id="uploadOutputPanel">  

            <h:panelGrid id="uploadPanelGridId" columns="2">  

                  <h:inputText value="#{adminModele.checkerNumber}"/> 
  <a4j:commandButton value="save"
  action="#{OperationController.add}"
  oncomplete="if (#{facesContext.maximumSeverity==null}){#{rich:component('LogAddDownloadPanel')}.hide();}"/> 

                   <h:outputText value="Uploaded File Name : #{adminModele.checkerNumber}"/>  

             </h:panelGrid>  
   </a4j:outputPanel>  

 </h:form>  

</rich:modalPanel>
```

Comment: Is it calling add() method in your backing bean? Print something at top of method and check if it prints.

Comment: yeaah i did that of course ,  if i take the button outside the rich:modalPanel it works fine , but when it's inside no action is taken onCLick

Comment: if you remove oncomplete from button does it work?

Comment: Noo it doesn't work

Comment: What if you remove rich:modalPanel ?

Comment: Make sure your `rich:modalPanel` (with form inside) is not part of other `h:form`. Nested forms are not supported.

Comment: Put #{OperationController} in some place of the xhtml so you can see if it is evaluated to null o you can see the .toString() of your bean (that will determine if your controller is alive). Btw where is your modal placed? Its part of another xhtml?

Answer (score 1):

Usually you access the beans with their name but the first letter "lower-case": 
(Applies for `@Named`, `@ManagedBean` or implicit with adding a scope such as `@RequestScoped`).

```
action="#{OperationController.add}"
```

did you explicit name the bean like that, or did you mean:

```
action="#{operationController.add}"
```

(from your `adminModele` I would assume the later...)

Keep in mind, this expressions are case-sensitive, but you should receive an error/warning about this: "Can't resolve variable Name" or similiar?

ps.: This does not apply if at least the first two letters are Upper Case:

> ...to support the occasional use of all upper-case names, we check if
>   the first two characters of the name are both upper case and if so
>   leave it alone. So for example, “FooBah” becomes “fooBah” “Z” becomes
>   “z” “URL” becomes “URL” We provide a method Introspector.decapitalize
>   which implements this conversion rule.

So, a Bean named `URLController` would not be accessed as `uRLController`, but with its original name.

Comment: no i explecitly named the bean OperationController with an Upper case